# Main won't properly call on function "makeArray"

Tags: c, arrays, function, 2d

I'm not quite sure what the issue is, but my function `makeArray` won't store values when reading the file, and so the array just spits out garbage instead of the values I need.

Here is my function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 12
#define COL 8

void makeArray(FILE *infile, int array[][8]) {
    int i, j;
    infile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            fscanf(infile, "%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(infile);
}
```

Here is main:

```
int main() {
    int choice, array[ROW][COL] = { 0 };
    FILE *infile;

    makeArray(infile, array);

    do {
        displayMenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        processRequest(array, choice);
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This entire code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 12
#define COL 8

void makeArray(FILE *infile, int array[][8]) {
    int i, j;

    infile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            fscanf(infile, "%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(infile);
}

int getScore(int array[][8], int month, int game) {

    int score;

    array[month-1][game-1] = score;

    return score;
}

int getMonthMax(int array[][8], int month) {

    int i, max;

    for (i = 0; i < COL; i++) {
        if (array[month - 1][i] > max) {
            max = array[month - 1][i];
        }
    }   
    return max;     
}

int getYearMax(int array[][8]) {

    int i, j, max;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] > max) {
                max = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

float getMonthAvg(int array[][8], int month) {

    int i, sum = 0, num = 0, j = 0;
    float avg;

    for (i = 0; i < COL; i++) {
        array[month - 1][i] = num;
        sum += num;
        j++;    
    }
    avg = (sum / j);
    return avg;
}

float getYearAvg(int array[][8]) {

    int i, j, k, sum = 0, num;
    float avg;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            array[i][j] = num;
            sum += num;
            k++;
        }
    }
    avg = (sum / k);
    return avg;
}

int toursMissed(int array[][8]) {

    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++){
            if (array[i][j] == 0)
                k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

void displayMenu() {

    int i, com;

    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\nSelect from option 1-7 or 0 to stop\n");
    printf("Select 1 to get the score for a specific game\n");
    printf("Select 2 to get the max score for a specific month\n");
    printf("Select 3 to get the average score for a specific month\n");
    printf("Select 4 to get the max score for the year\n");
    printf("Select 5 to get the average score for the year\n");
    printf("Select 6 to get the number of tournamnets missed for the year\n");
    printf("Select 7 to print all scores for the year\n");
    printf("Select 0 to stop\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");

}

void printArray(int array[][8]) {

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", &array[i][j]);   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void processRequest(int array[][8], int integer) {

    int f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8;
    int mont, gam;


    if (integer == 0) {
        printf("\nThank you!  Goodbye\n");
    }
    if (integer == 1) {
        printf("\nPlease enter the month and the game\n");
        scanf("%d%d", &mont, &gam);
        f1 = getScore(array, mont, gam);
        printf("\nThe score for Tournament %d is %d", gam, f1);
    }
    if (integer == 2) {
        printf("\nPlease enter the month\n");
        scanf("%d", &mont);
        f2 = getMonthMax(array, mont);
        printf("\nThe max score for month %d was %d\n", mont, f2);
    }
    if (integer == 3) {
        printf("\nPlease enter the month\n");
        scanf("%d", &mont);
        f3 = getMonthAvg(array, mont);
        printf("\nThe average score for month %d is %4.2f\n", mont, f3);
    }
    if (integer == 4) {
        f4 = getYearMax(array);
        printf("\nThe max score for the year is %d\n", f4);
    }
    if (integer == 5) {
        f5 = getYearAvg(array);
        printf("\nThe average score for the year is %4.2f\n", f5);
    }
    if (integer == 6) {
        f6 = toursMissed(array);
        printf("\nThe number of tournaments missed for the year is %d\n", f6);
    }
    if (integer == 7) {
        printf("\nThe scores for the year are:\n");
        printArray(array);
    }
}

int main() {

    int choice, array[ROW][COL] = { 0 };
    FILE *infile;

    makeArray(infile, array);

    do {
        displayMenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        processRequest(array, choice);
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if it's necessary to have all of that information available, but it's available now.

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue. It seems to be opening just fine @user3121023

Comment: at `getScore` : `array[month-1][game-1]=score;` --> `score = array[month-1][game-1];`

Comment: at : `getMonthAvg` : `array[i][j]=num;` --> `num = array[i][j];`, `avg=(sum/k);` --> `avg=(float)sum/k;`

Comment: at `toursMissed` : `int i,j,k;` --> `int i,j,k = 0;`

Comment: at `processRequest` : `int f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8;` --> `int f1,f2,f4,f6,f7,f8;float f3, f5;`

Comment: at `getMonthMax` and  `getYearMax` : `max` is uninitialized.

Comment: at `printArray` : `printf("%d\t",&array[i][j]);` --> `printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);`

Comment: at `getYearAvg` :  same mistake as `getMonthAvg` and `k` isn't initialize.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY I fixed all of those things, but for some reason the array still isn't working as it should. It's like it's just not reading the file, even though it definitely is. I need to go to work now, so I'll be available later. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- The main problem is you cannot tell if the array was read properly because the dump code in function `printArray()` is incorrect: `printf("%d\t", &array[i][j]);` should read `printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);`
- function `makeArray` takes a `FILE *infile` argument whose value is ignored. You should either make this argument a local variable or open the file in the caller and pass the `FILE*` or possibly pass the file name as an argument.
- You do not test any of the return values for correct completion: `fopen` can return `NULL` if the file cannot be opened.  Using a `NULL` stream pointer will invoke undefined behavior in most standard I/O functions.
- You do not test the return values of `scanf()` not `fscanf()`.  If incorrect input if provided, the program will invoke undefined behavior and the user will be clueless as to where to look for an explanation.  Check all return values and produce clear documented error messages.
- Function `getScore` is incorrect.  It should read:

  ```
  int getScore(int array[][8], int month, int game) {
      return array[month - 1][game - 1];
  }
  ```
- defining `COL` is useless if you hardcode the value of `COL` to 8 in your functions: the arrays are defined with the explicit constant instead of the `COL` macro.
- functions `getYearAvg()` and `getMonthAvg()` store `num` into the array instead of reading it from the array.  Furthermore, `avg` is not initialized to `0.0`.
- `k` is not initalized to `0` in `toursMissed()` not `getYearAvg()`.
- max should be initialized to `array[0][0]` in `getYearMax()` and `getMonthMax()`

In the end, `makeArray()` is the only function that will not fail, provided correct input.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! After adjusting the &array everything was solved. Thank you so so much! I also adjusted everything else.